# The minimum of the function is only taken on in the $(\sqrt{2\pi}c_{-N},...,\sqrt{2\pi}c_{N})$ where $c_{k}$ are fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb C$  be a riemann integrable function.

Let $F_{N}: \mathbb C^{2N+1} \to \mathbb R$,
$F_{N}(\gamma_{-N},...,\gamma_{N}):=\vert\vert f - \sum^{N}_{k=-N}\gamma_{k}\xi_{k}\vert\vert_{2} $, whereby $\xi_{k}: [0,2\pi]\to \mathbb C, \xi_{k}:=e^{ikx}/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

I am required to prove that the minimum value of $F_{N}$ only gets "taken on"/defined in:

($\sqrt{2\pi}c_{-N},...,\sqrt{2\pi}c_{N})$

where $(c_{k})_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ are the fourier coefficients of $f$.

Ideas:

$\vert\vert \sum^{\infty}_{k=N+1}c_{k}e^{ikx}+\sum^{-N-1}_{k=-\infty}c_{k}e^{ikx}+\sum^{N}_{k=-N}c_{k}e^{ikx}+\sum^{N}_{k=-N}\gamma_{k}\frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\vert\vert_{2}=\vert\vert \sum^{\infty}_{k=N+1}c_{k}e^{ikx}+\sum^{-N-1}_{k=-\infty}c_{k}e^{ikx}+\sum^{N}_{k=-N}e^{ikx}(c_{k}-\frac{\gamma{k}}{\sqrt{2\pi}})\vert\vert_{2}$

and $\sum^{N}_{k=-N}e^{ikx}(c_{k}-\frac{\gamma{k}}{\sqrt{2\pi}})=0 \ \Longleftrightarrow \gamma_{k}=\sqrt{2\pi}c_{k}$ $\forall k \in \{-N,...,N\}$ and therefore $F_{N}(\gamma_{-N},...,\gamma_{N}):=\vert\vert f - \sum^{N}_{k=-N}\gamma_{k}\xi_{k}\vert\vert_{2}$ is minimized.

Is this a sufficient proof seeing as though I have made no reference to the norm itself?

Answer (score 1):

Write $f$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients, then write explicitly what the norm is. You will notice that it will be a sum of squares with terms of type $(c_k-\gamma_k)^2$. The sum of positive terms is minimum when all those terms are $0$.

Comment: Now write this sum as three terms, one from $-\infty$ to $-N-1$, one a sum from $-N$ to $N$, and one from $N+1$ to $\infty$. Write out explicitly the norm.

Comment: Just use the first identity in your comment. Note that $\xi_{k}:=e^{ikx}/\sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: Write out $\gamma_k$. Then use the fact that you can write the norm squared as the product of a complex number and it's complex conjugate. Everywhere where you have $e^{ikx}$, the complex conjugate is $e^{-ikx}$

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78260/discussion-between-andrei-and-saboy).